# Get all tables and fields from glue data catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Thanks for taking your time to read this!

I have multiple tables within an AWS glue catalog database and want to create an ER diagram from that database.
It should contain all the fields and data types.

Is there a straightforward tool to achieve this, like pointing a schema creation tool like DBschema to the glue catalog?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a tool.  I would probably use boto3 for this (get a list of tables then the schema for each table), but that solution isn't as easy/slick as DbSchema